# Racket (Recursive structures and processing templates)

Tags: racket, recursive-datastructures, mutual-recursion, list-processing

I'm stumped on processing this structure, I want to write a function that tells how many topics occur in a discussion.

```
; a Discussion is (make-discussion String Digressions)
(define-struct discussion [topic digressions])

; Digressions is [ListOf Discussion]



; count-topics : Discussion -> Number
; counts the number of total topics in a discussion, including repeated topics

(define (count-topics d)
  (cond
    [(empty? (discussion-digressions d)) 0]
    [(cons?  (discussion-digressions d)) (add1 (count-topics (make-discussion (first (discussion-topic d))
                                                                                (list (make-discussion (rest (discussion-digressions d)))))))]))


(check-expect (count-topics  (make-discussion "music" (list (make-discussion "politics" empty)))) 2)
```

I've been trying for a few hours and haven't solved it yet. I'm not sure where to go from here, anybody have a sharp eye for Racket? I've tried to process the topic first, but haven't had any luck doing it that way.

Comment: There are two data definitions. One for `Discussion`, and one for `Digressions`, which are mutually recursive. If the structure of the program follows the structure of the data, there should be two functions, one for each datadef, which are mutually recursive in the same way the datadefs are.

Comment: One "code smell" within your code is recurring on a new constructed `make-discussion`, instead of a smaller sub-piece of the data. In [_Designing with Self-Referential Data Definitions_](https://htdp.org/2019-02-24/part_two.html#%28part._ch~3adesign-lists%29) for structural recursion, the natural recursion is always on a sub-piece of the original data, such as the result of a field selector, never on a new struct constructed right there

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `make-discussion` in your solution, we're trying to traverse the structures, not to create new ones. There are two cases to consider:

- If the `digressions` list is empty, then we've found one topic, and there's nowhere else to go.
- Otherwise, we count one topic (the current one) and call the recursion over *all the elements* in the list of `digressions`, adding their results. This is easy to implement using `apply` and `map`

This is what I mean:

```
(define (count-topics d)
  (cond
    [(empty? (discussion-digressions d)) 1]
    [else (add1 (apply + (map count-topics (discussion-digressions d))))]))
```

Of course you can solve this without using `apply` and `map`, but for that it's better to write separate procedures as Alex suggests. Anyway, my approach works as expected:

```
(count-topics
 (make-discussion "music"
                  (list (make-discussion "politics" empty))))
=> 2
```